# Regular Expressions in C++ on Xcode IDE

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to figure out what I can use for regular expressions. I am using Xcode 4.2 Lion but I am coding the back end of our application using C++. I have seen posts that mention boost but apparently that is not installed and I do not have the authority to add libraries on a whim.

I was hoping for a simple example of using the C POSIX regex library. The examples I was running into looked pretty brutal. I need to make a function that checks the format of the input string before I know how to convert it to nonoseconds.

pseudo code:

```
uint64_t MyClass::stringToTime(std::string time) {
    std::string tempTime;
    uint64_t number;
    // check the format
    if(time == regex(certain pattern)) {
        tmpTime = someStringManipulations;
    }
    else { // the format is this
        tmpTime = otherStringManipulations;
    }

    std::istringstream(temptime) >> number;
    return number; 
}
```

Comment: If you have to use C++, and you don't have a C++11 compiler, then using anything other than [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/) or [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/) is just masochistic IMO. Are you _sure_ you can't use Boost?

Comment: Xcode 4.2 uses clang primarily for its C++ and GCC as a second option. I can't compile with something the rest of the team is not using(eg intel composer or even changing to the C++11). This is a large code base with very busy svn. I'm not positive I can't use boost. I put a couple of includes up there and the build failed before I ever tried to code anything so I assumed it was not available.

Comment: If it eases things, Boost.Xpressive is header-only (i.e., no linking required), so you could use the [bcp](http://www.boost.org/tools/bcp/) tool to extract just that library's headers and commit them to your SVN without having the entirety of Boost as a dependency.

Comment: take a look into libpcre.. might help you out...

Comment: @Prasanth : I assume the OP _was_ referring to libpcre when he said "the c posix regex library".

Comment: ya.. sorry bout that mate...
@Miek : the only example that i know that uses libpcre is dansguardian but its kind of expert level with low documentation. but if you want to check, download it from here : http://dansguardian.org/downloads/2/Stable/ , exract it and there is RegExp.cpp and RegExp.hpp inside src folder. Check that out.